# How to replace difficult outside hose spigot handle?

Tags: faucet

The outside of the house is vinyl siding. I have a hose spigot where it attaches to the pipe, that seam is below the vinyl siding. What's more, I can't get the screw off to remove the handle. It's an old brass spigot with a metal handle that looks like a wheel. I've tried using liquid wrench on it and tapping it, which didn't work. Using a torch to loosen it will not work as it's 2mm from the vinyl siding.

Anyone have any other ideas to replace the handle? The spigot works fine but the handle is broken. I have a new metal handle I just want to replace the hold handle.

Should I drill out the screw and replace it? What are the screw specs for the replacement screw?

Thank you.

EDIT: The screw for the spigot handle requires a flathead screwdriver. It must be ancient. House was built in the 1950s but I think the spigot is newer than that.

I also have an air compressor but no air tools for it. If that helps.

---

EDIT: Adding images of the outside spigot in question.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Comment: Pic will have to wait until tonight. I'm at work now.

Comment: Pics added per request.

Comment: Thx. If you decide to try that hand impact screw driver tool that ArchonOSX suggested make sure to remove the hose and very securely support the spigot from below so when you start to hammer on it that you do not break the pipe going into the wall. The support could be a carefully cut piece of 2x4 going down to rest on a solid base on the ground.

Comment: Can you remove that old broken grounding strap? Not sure just what that is doing there now.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't stripped the screw head, they sell impact screw drivers for just such a situation. Like [this](https://www.zoro.com/proto-impact-driver-and-bit-set-38in-dr-13-pc-j7099a/i/G1106621/?gdffi=047ada998cf641fa93e55ae8579df863&gdfms=838028589E7F44D9B37578E5571B8227&gclid=CjwKEAjw6sC5BRCogcaY_dKZ2nESJABsZihxLJFBzNTMSPYOP15FDj9UgdSpJMgb1vLDSKdfdrKE4hoCggLw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) one.

A tool like this allows you to strike the impact with a hammer while turning the screw. They use them for motorcycle cases with Phillips screws that otherwise would never come loose with hand pressure alone. It you could rent one for a few dollars it would save you some money.

Your next step is to drill out the screw and re-tap the faucet stem.

Good luck!

Comment: FYI. I do have an air compressor but not many tools for it.

Comment: @bulrush you don't need an air compressor for an impact screw driver... but since you have one, then indeed, an air/impact wrench/ratchet should also work.